# 405 Method Not Allowed: The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I have been developing a system but I recently have not been able to debug why I get this error
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
I have been developing a system
I assume the problem has to do with the post function not being allowed and being interrupted by something please assist me thx.
code:

python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def student():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form['name']
        print(result)
        return "thank you for filling out this form"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
file_object = open('transferfile.txt', 'a+')
name = "Gabriel"
age = "12"
gender = "male"
file_object.write(name)
file_object.write(" ")
data = file_object.read(100)
file_object.write(age)
file_object.write(" ")
file_object.write(gender)
file_object.close()
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>venuefast</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="logo" action="." method="post">fastvenue<br>
        <hr>
        <input type ="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the student function is rendering the form in index.html, it only makes sense that the student function accepts POST requests:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def student():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        return f"thank you for filling out this form {name}!"
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/result')
def result():
    return 'this function does nothing yet'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

an alternative, if you are planning to use student for something else, you can make result function renders index.html instead and also make it accept POST requests:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def student():
    return 'this function does nothing yet'


@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        return f"thank you for filling out this form {name}!"
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This in the HTML

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>venuefast</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="logo" action="/result" method="POST">
        <p>fastvenue</p>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <input type ="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```